# Vim syntax highlighting 'else:' for Python

Tags: python, vim, syntax-highlighting, vim-syntax-highlighting

I'm getting annoyed with the default python syntax highlighting in Vim.

It does not highlight the `else:` statement correctly.
Vim only highlights the else statement if I have some white space between the `else` and the colon `:`, so `else :` works, but `else:` does not.

It must be easy to fix.

I'm using Vim 7.2

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I had below statement in my vimrc file. This made else: be tokenized as one word. After removing that else: syntax highlighting works just fine.

`set iskeyword+=:`

Comment: To get a similar effect, you could just add a syntax rule just for a colon that then links the highlighting for Keyword.

Comment: Are you sure the command is correct? `+=:` had no effect for me, `-=:` that Mark Roberts mentions did.

Comment: To clarify, `set iskeyword+=:` *is the offending line to be removed*.

Answer (score 5):

This periodically pops up, and I've taken to putting this in my vimrc:

```
" No seriously, else: is the same as else
autocmd BufEnter,BufRead,BufNewFile *.py    set iskeyword-=:
```

Comment: However, this means that the colon will not be highlighted as well. One might like this or dislike this fact.

Comment: I like this answer.  If you search under cursor with "*", you don't want it to match ":".

Answer (score 4):

It should work by default.

Look for a file that is something like this:

```
/usr/share/vim/vim72/syntax/python.vim
```

There should be a line there that looks like this:

```
syn keyword pythonConditional   if elif else
```

If not, investigate further. Does `elif` work?

Answer (score 4):

Note that the file in

```
/usr/share/vim/vim72/syntax/python.vim
```

is not up to date for some reason.

Get the most recent version of the syntax highlight file from http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=790

Comment: This indeed brought a change in combination with the answer by Mark Roberts.

Answer (score 1):

Enable the filetype stuff so things are setup automatically.
I've python auto indenting and syntax highlighting setup for vim here:
http://www.pixelbeat.org/settings/.vimrc

Answer (score 1):

In my ~/.vim/syntax/python.vim file, I have a line

```
syn keyword pythonConditional   else:
```

which solves this problem.