# python syntax highlight with gvim

Tags: python, vim, syntax-highlighting

I am writing `python` code in `gvim`, and I have added few plugins for doing that as well.
I am using [SlateDark](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=4757) theme (but i have checked other color schemes and saw thats a general problem)
The problem I am facing is that, when `keywords` are followed by a `:`,
like:

```
if this:
  <do things>
else:          #<=not highlighted
  <do that>
```

the `else:` does not get highlighted. I have to put a space there, as:

```
if this:
  <do things>
else :        #<= highlighted
  <do that>
```

But then, my pep8 checker says:

```
E203 whitespace before ':'
```

So, is it possible to edit something either in `colorscheme` or in `vimrc` that the keywords are still highlighted, when followed by `:`?

**EDIT**
  I have checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1393075/vim-syntax-highlighting-else-for-python?rq=1) thread. 
I already have

```
set iskeyword+=:
```

in my `vimrc`. Also my `python.vim` contains line:

```
syn keyword pythonConditional   elif else if
```

as two suggested solution in that thread.
My .vimrc is [here](http://bpaste.net/show/246650/).

NB: I have seen same thing in `fortran` as well. May be same bug in both script.

Comment: That's not a colorscheme problem, but a bug in the `syntax/python.vim` syntax plugin; you should report this to its author.

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1393075/vim-syntax-highlighting-else-for-python?rq=1

Comment: You don't want the set `iskyeword+=:`